# Write a js program to create map_armstrong function

Tags: javascript

Create a function with two parameters **pre_map** and **arr**. Where **pre_map** will be an in-built map provided to you through our test cases and **arr** will be an array of numbers. For each element from the given array, your function should check whether that element exists in your given **pre_map** as one of its **key** or not.

- eg:

  - pre_map { 0 => true, 1 => true, 10 => false, 19 => false, 370 => true }
  - arr [10, 407]
- If it exists then, `delete` it from the **pre_map**

  - eg:

    - pre_map { 0 => true, 1 => true, 19 => false, 370 => true }
- otherwise, `add a new key` in that given **pre_map** where its value will be a boolean value as either `true` or `false` based upon whether that key is an *`armstrong number`* or not. (Remember Armstrong Numbers from your previous repo?)

  - eg:

    - pre_map { 0 => true, 1 => true, 19 => false, 370 => true , 407 => true}
- Then, return your updated map (**pre_map**)

```js
function task09(pre_map, arr) {
  let obj = Object.fromEntries(pre_map);
  function isArmstrong(number) {
    if (number < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    let num_to_str = number.toString();
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < num_to_str.length; i++) {
      let num = parseInt(num_to_str[i]);
      sum += Math.pow(num, num_to_str.length);
    }
    return (number == sum);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let entry = arr[i].toString();
    if (obj.entry !== undefined) {
      delete obj.entry;
    } else {
      obj.entry = isArmstrong(parseInt(entry));
    }
  }
  return new Map(Object.entries(obj));
}
```

What's wrong with my code and why is it not passing some test cases.

Comment: I think the issue is your `isArmstrong()` function. An Armstrong number is "_a number that is equal to the sum of cubes of its digits_" therefore you should replace `sum += Math.pow(num, num_to_str.length);` with `sum += Math.pow(num, 3);`

Comment: thanks, I made the change but it's still not passing the test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT: as it is not clear from the requirements whether the original map should be modified directly or not, I am adding a second solution]

#### Solution 1 (the original map is modified directly):

```js
function task09(pre_map, arr) {
  function isArmstrong(num) {
    if (num < 0) return false;
    
    const numToStr = num.toString();
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < numToStr.length; i++) {
      sum += Math.pow(parseInt(numToStr[i]), 3);
    }

    return num === sum;
  }

  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (pre_map.has(item)) {
      pre_map.delete(item);
    } else {
      pre_map.set(item, isArmstrong(item));
    }
  });
  
  return pre_map;
}


/********
 * test *
 ********/

const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, true);
myMap.set(1, true);
myMap.set(10, false);
myMap.set(19, false);
myMap.set(370, true);

const myArr = [10, 407];

console.log('myArr:', myArr);
console.log('myMap (before):');
for (let item of myMap) {
  console.log(item);
}

task09(myMap, myArr);

console.log('myMap (after):');
for (let item of myMap) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

#### Solution 2 (the original map is NOT modified):

```js
function task09(pre_map, arr) {
  const post_map = new Map(pre_map);

  function isArmstrong(num) {
    if (num < 0) return false;

    const numToStr = num.toString();
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < numToStr.length; i++) {
      sum += Math.pow(parseInt(numToStr[i]), 3);
    }

    return num === sum;
  }

  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (post_map.has(item)) {
      post_map.delete(item);
    } else {
      post_map.set(item, isArmstrong(item));
    }
  });

  return post_map;
}


/********
 * test *
 ********/

const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, true);
myMap.set(1, true);
myMap.set(10, false);
myMap.set(19, false);
myMap.set(370, true);

const myArr = [10, 407];

const myUpdatedMap = task09(myMap, myArr);

console.log('myArr:', myArr);
console.log('myMap:');
for (let item of myMap) {
  console.log(item);
}
console.log('myUpdatedMap:');
for (let item of myUpdatedMap) {
  console.log(item);
}
```